# How to filter out elements that don't match regexp?

Tags: regex, matlab

For example, suppose that the variable `strings` is a cell containing strings, like this:

```
strings = {'alpha' 'basis' 'colic' 'druid' 'even' 'fluff' 'golf'};
```

I want to filter `strings` so as to end up only with strings that have matching first and last characters.  IOW, the result from this operation should be

```
{'alpha' 'colic' 'druid' 'fluff'}
```

More generally,

> I want to filter a cell array of strings to remove all the strings that fail to match some regular expression.

For the example above, I can get the desired result with the following logical array

```
~~cellfun(@numel, regexp(strings, '^(.).*\1$'))
```

IOW,

```
>> strings(~~cellfun(@numel, regexp(strings, '^(.).*\1$')))
ans = 
    'alpha'    'colic'    'druid'    'fluff'
```

But `~~cellfun(@numel, regexp(strings, '^(.).*\1$'))` is an unreadable monstrosity.

Is there a clearer way to filter a cell array so as to retain the matches to a regular expression?

---

EDIT: based on excaza's answer, I defined the following functions:

```
% grep.m
function filtered = grep(pattern, cellarray)
%GREP find matches to PATTERN in a cell array of strings.
%     GREP(PATTERN, CELLARRAY) returns a cell array
%     containing all the strings in CELLARRAY that match the
%     regular expression PATTERN.  CELLARRAY is expected to
%     be a cell array of strings.

    filtered = cellarray(matchq(cellarray, pattern));
end

% matchq.m
function yn = matchq(string, pattern)
%MATCHQ predicate stating whether STRING matches PATTERN.
%   If STRING is a single string, MATCHQ(STRING, PATTERN)
%   returns a logical value corresponding to whether or not
%   STRING matches pattern.  If STRING is a cell array of
%   strings, MATCHQ(STRING, PATTERN) returns a logical vector
%   whose i-th entry equals MATCHQ(STRING{i}, PATTERN).

    if ischar(string)
        yn = ~isempty(regexp(reshape(string, 1, []), pattern, 'match'));
    else
        assert(iscellstr(string));
        yn = cellfun(@(s) matchq(s, pattern), string);
    end
end
```

With these definitions,

```
>> grep('^(.).*\1$', strings)
ans = 
    'alpha'    'colic'    'druid'    'fluff'
```

FWIW, `grep` still "works" even if `strings` consists of arbitrarily-shaped character vectors:

```
>> grep('^(.).*\1$', {['aus';'tra';'lia'], ['basis']', ['ce';'lt';'ic'], ...
                      ['dia';'led'], 'early', ['foo';'lpr';'oof'], ...
                      ['gyp';'sum']})
ans = 
    [3x3 char]    [3x2 char]    [2x3 char]    [3x3 char]

>> cellfun(@(c) reshape(c', [], 1)', ans, 'UniformOutput', false)
ans = 
    'australia'    'celtic'    'dialed'    'foolproof'
```

Comment: Use `'^(?!(.).*\1$)'` or `'^(?!(.).*\1$).*'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: `regexp('^(?!(.).*\1$)', strings)` evaluates to the equivalent of `repmat({[]}, 1, numel(strings))`.  Ditto for `regexp('^(?!(.).*\1$).*', strings)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [`regexp`'s documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) you can utilize the [`'match'` output keyword](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#input_argument_outkey) to request only the return the text that matches your expression. `regexp` operates on cell arrays natively so there isn't any need to call it with `cellfun`. However, to ensure `regexp`'s robustness, it has the (often annoying) [behavior](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#output_argument_out) of returning a cell array of cells, where each cell corresponds to the output of `regexp` for the input cell.

This leads to the following scenario:

```
strings = {'alpha' 'basis' 'colic' 'druid' 'even' 'fluff' 'golf'};
matches = regexp(strings, '^(.).*\1$', 'match');
```

Which returns:

```
matches =

  1×7 cell array

    {1×1 cell}    {}    {1×1 cell}    {1×1 cell}    {}    {1×1 cell}    {}
```

To get rid of the empty cells, you can use a basic loop or cellfun (essentially equivalent to a loop):

```
strings = {'alpha' 'basis' 'colic' 'druid' 'even' 'fluff' 'golf'};
matches = regexp(strings, '^(.).*\1$', 'match');
emptymask = cellfun('isempty', matches);
matches(emptymask) = [];
```

Which returns:

```
matches =

  1×4 cell array

    {1×1 cell}    {1×1 cell}    {1×1 cell}    {1×1 cell}
```

You will need one more step to denest the cells. This can be done with a simple loop or with `cellfun` (essentially equivalent to a loop):

```
strings = {'alpha' 'basis' 'colic' 'druid' 'even' 'fluff' 'golf'};
matches = regexp(strings, '^(.).*\1$', 'match');
emptymask = cellfun('isempty', matches);
matches(emptymask) = [];
matches = cellfun(@(x) x{:}, matches, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Which returns:

```
matches =

  1×4 cell array

    'alpha'    'colic'    'druid'    'fluff'
```

---

If you can assume that there should only be one match per cell of your input cell (or string) array, then you can use the [`'once'` search option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#input_argument_option) to eliminate one layer:

```
strings = {'alpha' 'basis' 'colic' 'druid' 'even' 'fluff' 'golf'};
matches = regexp(strings, '^(.).*\1$', 'match', 'once');
```

Which returns:

```
matches =

  1×7 cell array

    'alpha'    ''    'colic'    'druid'    ''    'fluff'    ''
```

This can be passed through the same mask as the naive approach:

```
strings = {'alpha' 'basis' 'colic' 'druid' 'even' 'fluff' 'golf'};
matches = regexp(strings, '^(.).*\1$', 'match', 'once');
emptymask = cellfun('isempty', matches);
matches(emptymask) = [];
```

Which returns:

```
matches =

  1×4 cell array

    'alpha'    'colic'    'druid'    'fluff'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Based on your post, I wrote a couple of routines to fill the gap in MATLAB's built-in library.  See the EDIT to my post.  (To MathWorks: please implement these functions!)